# Qt toDouble() method cast to int

Tags: c++, qt, casting, double

I have a problem casting to double. I'm casting two string to double, one is well casted, the other is casted to int, yet this is the same code ..

```
QTextStream lecture(&file);
ligne = lecture.readLine();
double x = ligne.split(" ")[0].toDouble();
double y = ligne.split(" ")[1].toDouble();
std::cout << " x en string = " <<ligne.split(" ")[0].toStdString() << "; y en string = " << ligne.split(" ")[1].toStdString() <<  std::endl;
std::cout << " x = " << x << "; y = " << y <<  std::endl;
```

This is the result

```
x en string = 988284.9; y en string = 6429241.49999999
x = 988285; y = 6.4496e+06
```

If you see the result, the x is not decimal ..

Comment: can you tell us what is ligne?

Comment: Yes I edited my post. But the string conversion is ok, so I don't think it comes from ligne

Comment: that is just rounding I believe

Comment: what if u assign the numeric value directly to x. just to ensure it is not a kind of formating problem

Comment: That's say ? The base format is in a file text. I'm directly assign it to x in double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x has actually the correct value.

Your issue is actually here :

```
std::cout << " x = " << x ;
```

Because you have a default precision of 6 digits, which isn't enough to represent the ".9". It should be something like:

```
std::cout << " x = " << std::setprecision(8) << x
```

which output a better value:

```
x = 988284.9; y = 6429241.5
```

Note: you need

```
#include <iomanip>
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision additionnal info on setprecision() (and other stream manipulators)

Comment: What do you mean ? The assign (double x = ligne.split(" ")[0].toDouble();) is fine, it's your output that is wrong (feel free to ask details in English and in French, I'll answer using both languages.)

Comment: Ho okey, so if I want to use x, I can be sure that it contains the value with its precision ?

Comment: x contains 988284.9. Using it later (addition, etc.) will use its value (988284.9). However, when you do a std::cout, you only get a limited number of digits (6 is the default, and 6 digits of 988284.9 = 988285 - rounded to the closest). If you want to see more digits, you need to ask for more using setprecision(). But this is only for the output using std::cout, x alone is fine. Note: for numbers with a big number of digits, you may have a small difference between the string and the double, as double has also a limited precision (that should be enough).